# Android static library to shared library

Tags: android, automake, android-build

I added a module in the directory of **framework/av/**

The code can be built when the `Android.mk` ended with the line

`include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)` .

However, since I need a shared library file (say abcd.so),
I changed this line to

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then I got errors which refer to some undefined reference errors.

Did I need to change anything here?

### Thanks

```
out/target/product/abcd/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libudev_intermediates/libudev.o: in function udev_new:frameworks/av/libudev/libudev.c:195: error: undefined reference to 'secure_getenv'
target 
Symbolic: libcutils (out/target/product/abcd/symbols/system/lib/libcutils.so)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/target/product/abcd/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libudev_intermediates/LINKED/libudev.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: please, show the compiler log.

Comment: making static libraries doesn't give you undefined reference errors because it assumes that they will be found when it's linked to the actual dynamic library or the executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the android system, there are many other modules which are depending on **static** *av* module. I suggest you build both *static* library and *shared* library. Even if you make a shared library, you should take care of the dependence. These changing may lead other problems.

And the codes looks like these:

```
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
#appending this line for shared library
LOCAL_MODULE := xxx_shared
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```